# What to do when a question you have asked with a bounty is not receiving any interaction/attention?

Tags: discussion, bounty

What should I do when a question I have asked with a bounty is not receiving any interaction/attention? I have answered all commenter's questions thoroughly. I edited the question recently to update its formatting. I know that it is against SE rules to repost on math.SE about the question, but as I have still gotten nowhere further with the question I am not sure what course of action to take.

The question is here:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/241646/planar-graphs-all-equivalent-to-null-graph-by-equivalence-relation

Thank you,
George

Answer (score 30):

Your question was asked on the 20th of November.  Five days is by no means a long time for a question to go unanswered.

Unless of course you are in hurry to obtain the answer, because this is [question 9 from MIT PRIMES-USA](http://mit.edu/primes/materials/2013/entproUSA13.pdf), and ongoing competition whose deadline is November 26th.

Comment: Problem 10 as I see the pdf.

Comment: I recognize several of the questions there as having been posted to m.se. This is hugely annoying!

Comment: Problem 1 is essentially http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/206945/coin-toss-tails-divisibility

Comment: Problem 2a is http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/208929/at-least-a-sqrtn-solutions

Comment: Problem 3 is pretty much http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/233269/odd-and-even-numbers-in-pascals-triangle-sierpinskis-triangle

Comment: Problem 4 is http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/211333/sequence-of-solutions-to-x-sin-x-1

Comment: Problem 5 is http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/231810/applying-a-function-to-square-matrices

Comment: I have sent email to the organizer to direct his attention to this page.

Comment: I wonder if it is five different people, or one person with various aliases.

Answer (score 6):

If people would include the source of a given problem as part of the process of posting a question, things would get a little easier.

Comment: Yes, but posting problems of an ongoing contest is really unethic...

Comment: Probably it is only unethical if someone obtains a solution on math.se, then presents it as his own work to the contest.

Comment: @BeniBogosel, I agree. I asked a related thing a few days earlier, http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6629/another-contest-problem  where it turned out the question on Main was not really from a current contest. My preference would be that nobody post current contest or examination questions, and homework or self-study question or past exam/contest questions would include the book title, author, and page number, for exams or contests the year. Maybe a jpeg image of the original, in case there is doubt about translation of the question into English.